# Import Error: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I am working on an object detection model in google colab and I'm following most of the instructions outlined [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html).

In order to train the model, I am trying to use:

```
!python model_main_tf2.py 
!python --model_dir=models/SSD_640
!python --pipeline_config_path=models/SSD_640/pipeline.config
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/Workspace
2021-06-28 11:33:33.510377: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/__init__.py)
```

The mentioned file `model_lib_v2.py` is available in the following path - `Workspace/models/research/model_lib_v2.py`

I've tried adjusting the cd to point to the workspace folder by using the code:

```
%cd '/content/drive/MyDrive/Workspace'
```

I have also been trying to fix it by trying to install `object_detection` again, but this has not helped. I also made sure that the paths are correct, and there do not seem to be any inconsistencies.

Any help on this would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

model_lib_v2.py have to be in the folder object_detection.

Try to add  to PYTHONPATH.

You can get the files from here.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection